# How to add /bigobj parameter to msbuild

Tags: msbuild, compiler-options

I got Visual Studio solution, that generates big objects ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173499%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))
How and which option should I pass to ask msbuild to generate big objects?

Comment: Using MSBuild from the Command Line is different than using the Visual Studio IDE. Its a very poor duplicate at best. The question probably should have remained open so it could be answered.

Comment: The proposed duplicates speak to Visual Studio configuration, not the msbuild command line tool. This was not a duplicate and it comes up near the top of a google search for this question.

Answer (score -1):

See the following:
[How do I edit Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Compiler switches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692055/how-do-i-edit-microsoft-visual-studio-2013-compiler-switches/20692056#20692056)

**See also:**

[Penalty of the MSVS compiler flag /bigobj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110580/penalty-of-the-msvs-linker-flag-bigobj)

[Build issue with MSVS 2010 and the C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578017/build-issue-with-msvs-2010-and-the-c-standard/10578080#10578080)

[How to compile with /bigobj within Dymola (Modelica)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150053/how-to-compile-with-bigobj-within-dymola-modelica)

Comment: I here for invite [you to Meta to join the discussion about these answers of yours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212752/strange-search-engine-optimization-in-answers).

Comment: These answers speak to setting this option in the Visual Studio GUI application. The question is regarding the MSBUILD command line tool.